# can we change ngIf to hidden in Angular library explicitely

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material's [Tab](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api). And i am suppose to add and remove class using:

```
const classotherClustersSelection = document.getElementsByClassName('others');
    Array.from(classotherClustersSelection).forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('others');
    })
```

On change of a particular data i am suppose to remove class from the tabs section, from  all tabs. But unfortunately other tab that contains 'others' class is hidden with ng-if, so i am not able to manipulate the DOM directly. Whats are the approaches possible?

Comment: Having `*ngIf` doesn't hide the element, it removes it from the DOM.

Comment: i mean, its not available in dom. Had they used [hidden], my work would have been done.

Comment: It would be good if you recreate this issue on Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that *ngIf not hide the element, it removes it completle from the dom.
That's why you are not able to access the element.

If you want to hide something but still access it, you should remove the element by style.
You can use class or style binding for that:

**style binding:**

```
<div [style.display]="conditionForHide ? 'none' : 'initial'">
```

**class binding:**

```
<div [class.removeClass]="conditionForHide">
```

For the second option you need to create the class in you style sheet. An example to remove the element without display:

```
.conditionForHide {
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

## Edit

You should not manipulate the material code. And angular offers you a couple of options to manipulate your code next to plane javascript (getElementsByClassName).

The fastest way is when the data change is triggered, you manipulate the class via class binding:

Controller:

```
public showClassOthers = true;

onDataChange() {
  // do some tasks
  this.showClassOthers = false;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First" [class.others]="showClassOthers"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second" [class.others]="showClassOthers"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Thats completely right. And if i use [hidden] this will work. But the problem that its an external library 'Angular material' and tabs that i am using belongs to it only. *ngIf is provided by that library. I want to manipulate this external library somehow. [Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api) Please take a look here.

Comment: I edit my answer. If it still not what you need, please provide more details (for example some code snippets)

Answer (score 0):

Add ngClass property to your div like I did below:

```
<div [ngClass]="{others: boolClass}" *ngIf="data==='requiredValue'"></div>
```

Then change the value of boolClass variable where the data gets changed:

```
this.data = 'someOtherValue';
this.boolCass = (this.boolClass)?(this.data==='requiredValue'): false;
```

Now the class will be removed from the element.
You can refer from my example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cc6tru

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to Conditionally add/remove the class from the DOM element.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spckrn)

In Demo, I am changing the data on button click and based on the value class is added or removed.